# Swipe to go back in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ios, jquery-mobile

Using jquery mobile, how would I enable the ability to swipe right and go back to my main page? Sort of how putting in a back button enables and automatic return to the previous page, I would like that for swipe right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to bind to swiperight

```
$(document).bind('swiperight', function () {
    history.back();
});
```

I have created a Fiddle to show you, what you have to do. Look here, http://jsfiddle.net/wumm/WHT69/!

Comment: Thanks, javascript isnt really my strong point. Now does that need to be placed in each page that I want to be to swipe or just place it in my head?

Comment: Place it in head, then every page can swipe, If you don't want that every page can swipe, list the ids of the pages you wanted to swipe, where now is document(like: '#page1, #page2'). Then place it in head.